# Unity Particle System appearing behind other sprites

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite, particle-system, behind

I have a particle system BloodSpill that is Instantiated when the player dies by:

```
Instantiate(bloodSpillEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation);
```

However, it will appear behind all other sprites (background, ground etc.) NO MATTER what I do. I have the particle system as a prefab and it's sorting layer is set as the same as the player's both programatically and through the options. It's position on the Z axis is also closer to the camera than other objects.

Actually, if I drag one from the prefabs folder and put it in the scene it will appear in front of other sprites, but when I instantiate it through the line of code above it will not show up.

I don't know and am unable to find information on what the difference is between dragging and dropping it from the folder and using Instantiate().

Comment: Didin't you add that script to all objects accidentally?
Is something that you Instatiated showing in the hierarchy?
try:
    Debug.Log (Instantiate(bloodSpillEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation));
or:
    GameObject test = Instantiate(bloodSpillEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;
Debug.Log (test);
If any of this returns null, it's mean that you instantiate that in the wrong way.

Comment: It is instantiated and it is showing in the hierarchy. The problem is that it is showing behind all other sprites while it shouldn't be.

Comment: Again, if I drag and drop it from the prefabs folder on the scene it will show above everything like it should, but if I instantiate it with Instantiate() it will show behind all other sprites.

Comment: Isn't it caused by the fact, that you Instantiate that in the transform.position?

Comment: transform.postion contains also z axis.

Comment: Instantiate(bloodSpillEffect, new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, -0.1f), transform.rotation);

Doesn't seem to work either...

Comment: So maybe Z axis is not the problem.

Comment: Try adjust sorting layer of the partcile system.

Comment: For some weird reason today when I tried it started working as intended. Thank you for your help!